# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' (class timer.php)

Tags: php, syntax-error

I have a syntax error at the line: `return (double) + (double);`

```
   public function getMicroTime( )
    {
        list( $usec, $sec ) = explode( " ", microtime( ) );
        return (double) + (double);
    }
```

Could you help me to resolve this please ?

Comment: What is `double` supposed to be? Have you defined a constant?

Comment: what do you actully think you are going to return ? 2 doubles make a quadruple ?

Comment: I would point out also that unless you plan to do something with `$usec, $sec`, this function is doing _nothing whatsoever of use_. It doesn't return those values.

Comment: Besides the mentioned unclear use of `double` variable, you should know that is a reserved word, so just in case you use it as a constant name - you shouldn't

Comment: Ah, this looks like a misinterpretation of the [`microtime()` docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php), which have the example `return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);`

Answer (score 2):

The `(double)` type cast behaves much like a unary operator and thus requires an argument next to it. You should return the following instead:

```
return (double)$usec + (double)$sec;
```

However, since 5.0, your whole function can be replaced by simply this:

```
microtime(true);
```

By passing `true` as the first argument, it returns the time as a float with ms accuracy.

Comment: your gravatar wears the Monarch By Right hat perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks! I see that your camel's head has all but disappeared under funky Gandalf's pointy hat ;-)

Comment: Yeah my camel's too tall to wear any of them, really :(

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Perhaps the bow tie would fit =D

Comment: [Indeed.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/541091/michael-berkowski)

Answer (score 1):

google finds this, based on your vars, you may be missing something in your copy and paste skills :-)

```
function getmicrotime($t) {  
 list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ",$t);  
 return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);  
}
```